# Will quantum computers of the future be operational under room temperatures (above 0 Celsius)?

Tags: open-quantum-systems

In the future of Quantum Computing, will it be possible to see quantum computers operating under room temperature like the personal classical computers or normal laptops that we have currently?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would suggest to ask if it is possible to have quantum computer working in room temperature environment. If so, what progress is necessary, in for example superconducting materials etc. If no, what phenomenon prevents QC from the possibility to operate at the room temperature.

Answer (score 7):

It is extremely hard to talk with certainty about the future when talking about quantum computation. Nevertheless, there *are* fair things we can say about the closely related question

> *Is it theoretically possible to have quantum computation with room temperature qubits?*

The answer to this question is, to the best of my knowledge, (a careful) yes: through [photonic quantum computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_optical_quantum_computing). In this setting, qubits are designed using photons and quantum computation is carried with room temperature linear photonic devices ([see this presentation, minute 3:43](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62Y7uT26hzo) when author talks about no need for mK temperatures and scalability, [see also this presentation, minute 3:58](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJuHiKMYOzI&t=1710s) where Terry Rudolph says that in principle photonic quantum computers could be at room temperature; [see also this presentation, minute 18:36](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQRmSOKgMPA) where they explain that only the detectors need to be cooled down, and much less then for superconducting qubits).

You may need to cool down the detectors nevertheless, but this is far easier than the *entire* quantum computer. Moreover, photonic quantum computation implements one-way quantum computation models and there are results showing this kind of computation to be [fault-tolerant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11780), [universal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4NAqTHRYD4&pp=ugMICgJlbhABGAE%3D), [heralded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqAWSa0bV9Y) and even have big companies that are building these devices like Psi-Quantum and Xanadu (to the best of my knowledge, there might be others).

If these devices will be used to build scalable fault-tolerant quantum computers is still to be experimentally shown, but there is evidence pointing in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the quantum computers developed worldwide work with so-called qubits.

These only work at temperatures close to absolute zero.

A degree above absolute zero is boiling hot for a quantum computer.

This will be even more difficult in the future, but solutions are on the way, with uses of simples components.

**From Stanford team's:**

> Perhaps one of the greatest benefits of the Stanford team's new system is that it can operate at room temperatures, meaning it may help to vastly reduce the complexity of these machines, which promise to revolutionize the problem-solving capacity of computers.

**Source:** [A New, Simpler Quantum Computer Runs at Room Temperature](https://interestingengineering.com/new-simpler-quantum-computer-runs-at-room-temperature)

**Researchers from University of Copenhagen:**

> Developed a new technique that keeps quantum bits of light stable at room temperature.

**Source:** [Quantum Breakthrough: New Invention Keeps Qubits of Light Stable at Room Temperature](https://scitechdaily.com/quantum-breakthrough-new-invention-keeps-qubits-of-light-stable-at-room-temperature/)

Take a look at this report:

[The world’s first room-temperature quantum computer brings the future a step closer](https://dug.com/the-worlds-first-room-temperature-quantum-computer-brings-the-future-a-step-closer/).

The future will show us how far it will be possible.

Let's look at the history of our 2nd generation of computers what has happened within 40 years. I mean how size has developed into power.

[Future of Quantum Computing in 2022: In-Depth Guide](https://research.aimultiple.com/future-of-quantum-computing/)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this: *Let's look at the history of our 2nd generation of computers what has happened within 40 years*. Do you mean a history of classical computers?

Comment: I mean how size has developed into power. Giant computer hardware low power in the passt and now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).